# How can i make a README structure like this?

Tags: github

How can I make a README.md like this person has done in his repository?
https://github.com/RodneyShag/HackerRank_solutions/blob/master/readme.md

Do I have to copy paste links of all of my files ? or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to put all the files manually.

Or create a script which will generate the file for you. Either way Markdown is a simple text file.

Comment: What type of script ? or how can I create it? Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Ok sir, thanks for answering my question. :) Have a nice day